# How can I get rid of 403 error on uvdesk?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, iis

I'm getting an error when trying to use uvdesk
I'm on IIS Windows server, PHP v8.3, MySQL last version on uvdesk (fresh install)

I managed to get the site "ok" i can add articles BUT when i want to change the status to published I get this error :

Error: Something went wrong, please try again later

```
/public/fr/member/article/ajax/2 403
```

I tried to put rights for everyone and no change.
Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: 1) If you read IIS log files, you might find such error code (with substatus) typical in IIS world, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code 2) Running PHP on IIS today is at your own risks, https://docs.phpmanager.xyz/getting-started/supported-platforms#php-on-windows-status 3) Such questions should be posted to the vendor forum or Server Fault, as server administration is different from programming.

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.